# How to create active menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how to create an active menu on my site. I mean my currently active menu element will be highlighted. How I can do this?

I have downloaded some templates and they have this feature but they use a class named "active" but this class automatically comes to currently active menu element. Do they use any javascript for that?

Please help me.

Regards,
Abdul

Comment: Do you have any current code examples? Is your site just static html files? if so can you at least post your menu.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. No, my site is only a static html site. Please check this template- http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_391_botany/ This template has this currently active menu feature. I want to know how to do this.

Comment: You could manually add 'active' class to the respective menu item in each page.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any javascript used to add the `active` class to the respective `li` element. Since these are static html files, you can add in the `class="active"` line yourself into the HTML for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo of how addition of 'active' class works with jquery.Hope this helps.

```
//HTML portion

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    </ul>

//CSS portion    
    <style type="text/css">
    .active
    {
        color:#0CC;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    </style>

//JAVASCRIPT portion 

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul.nav li a").click(function() {
            $("ul.nav li a").removeClass("active"); //This is important to make only one link active at a time
            // Try without using above line and note the difference

            $(this).addClass("active"); // Add 'active' class to currently clicked element
        });    
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it is what you were looking for :)